# Jetpack Compose APK has colors off from AVD

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, uicolor

So I'm working on the UI for my app as everything else is done, and I can't seem to figure out what's going on with the colors. When I view the app in my AVD, everything is looking as expected. However, when I download the APK, everything is a weird shade of brown instead.

I have both the DarkColorScheme and LightColorScheme set to specific colors, and working as intended in the APK.

Originally I thought it was because I was using the debug APK, but it's the same on the release. I have no idea what's going on. Does anyone have any suggestions?

I'm using Android Studio 2022.2.1 if it helps.

This is how the app should look:
[image: how app looks on AVD]

This is how it looks running on my device:
[image: How the app looks on device]

Comment: Very interesting.  Following.

Comment: Edited to add images.

Comment: Could you be using dynamic theme color?

Comment: It may be taking on the color of the wallpaper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As can be seen from the screenshots, [DynamicColors](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/theming/dynamic-colors) are used.

You may consider turning it off on your [device](https://support.google.com/phoneapp/thread/189703895/how-to-disable-google-dynamic-color-change?hl=en).

DynamicColor disabled:

```
Theme.kt
```

---

```
val colorScheme = when {
        /*dynamicColor && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S -> {
            val context = LocalContext.current
            if (darkTheme) dynamicDarkColorScheme(context) else dynamicLightColorScheme(context)
        }*/ // removed condition state

        darkTheme -> DarkColorScheme
        else -> LightColorScheme
    }
```

Comment: That's looks to be it. Is there a way to disable dynamic colors so it doesn't happen to any other user? I just went off the standard empty compose for creating my app so that stuff was in by default and I'm only a month into learning it.

Comment: You can set it in the theme class of your project.

Comment: I am sharing the sample code.

Comment: I updated my answer, you can check it.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll get right on fixing it!

Comment: you're welcome.